# How can I make Primefaces selectonemenu in disabled state?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to use p:selectonemenu and make it disabled, i.e. it should be submitted during a post but it should be read-only. Please note that I do NOT want to use the disabled attribute as this will prevent posting.

I have read on this forum that this can be achieved by using a hidden field, however I do not understand how this can be implemented. I would appreciate if someone out there could provide me with some help in this regard.

```
<p:inputText id="cpr" value="#{customerbean.customer.cpr}">
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{customerbean.fetchCustomerDatafromCBS}" update="nationality address passportno name nationality dob address mailingaddress gender mobileno landlineno otherno email maritalstatus nochildren" immediate="true" >
         <f:param name="cprNumber" value="#{customerbean.customer.cpr}"/>
    </p:ajax>                 
    <f:validator validatorId="cprValidator" />                    
</p:inputText>   


<p:selectOneMenu id="gender" value="#{customerbean.customer.gender}" required="!#{customerbean.disabled}" requiredMessage="#{text['validation.error.required.gender']}" disabled="#{customerbean.disabled}">                      
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="Male" />  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Female" itemValue="Female"  />  
</p:selectOneMenu>                

<p:inputText  type="hidden" value="#{customerbean.customer.gender}" />
```

Comment: set the disabled attribute to true

Comment: Sorry, I should not have used the word "disabled" as it can be interpreted as referring to the attribute disabled. What I mean is that I want it to be in a read-only state as described in the text above. Using the disabled attribute will mean that the value will not be posted.

Comment: That's interesting. How will the component behave? Will it still be posted? Also, what is the difference between pe:blockui and p:blockui and which one should I use?

Comment: I dont see how I can get this to work? It seems to be some functionality related to Ajax submission? I need to disable this field AFTER ajax submission indefinitely.

Comment: I want to make it blocked after I enter a value into a field, run an Ajax query, fetch information and populate all fields on the screen including the selectOneMenu field. I dont have a problem making all other fields readonly except the selectOneMenu which does not support read-only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have read on this forum that this can be achieved by using a hidden
>   field, however I do not understand how this can be implemented.

Make the `<p:selectOneMenu>` disabled, and create a `<p:inputText type="hidden" value="#{bean.property}" />`. The `value` attribute must be the same as the `<p:selectOneMenu>`. If necessary, use the same converter.

This way, the `<p:selectOneMenu>` will be disabled to the user, but the value will be submitted by the hidden `<p:inputText />`.

---

Remember that the hidden input is still a `<p:inputText />`, and thus it needs to be updated when its value changes. Assign an ID to it, and make sure you add it to the `update` of your `<p:ajax />`.